# Is it possible to add a new language to Android devices

Tags: android, nexus-one

I have a Nexus One and I would like to know if it's possible to add a new language to the system? Or are the languages compiled into the kernel?

if it's possible where can I find information about creating/developing a language for Android?

Comment: Are you referring to programming language, or a written language like English or French?

Comment: `I wan't for example the locked screen to show the date in Icelandic. I have not programed anything for android, so it's possible to create a native app that overwrites/adds a local language to the system? – Bjarki Heiðar`  I *totally* misread your question. Sorry about that. I'm deleting my answer so I'll answer your other question here: I haven't delved deeply into it, but on the surface I don't think you could write a native app that overwrites the system language. However, you *could* write your own app that supports Icelandic for its UI.

Comment: I'm interested in the system lang, I know that I can have lang files for the apps. But thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a Nexus One and I would like to
>   know if it's possible to add a new
>   language to the system?

No, sorry, languages are part of the firmware.